# Texstudio toolbar graphics are big

Tags: graphics, texstudio

I've been using texstudio for a while on ubuntu 16.04, and one day the toolbar graphics became very big and very ugly[image]

They used to be smaller. I'm not sure but I think it has somtheing to do with a package I installed "libqt5scripttools".

Now I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! You can adjust the size of the toolbar in the preferences

Comment: Under `Configure TeXstudio -> GUI scaling`. You need to activate `Show Advanced Options` on the bottom left hand corner.